# Supplying data to an Angular directive (from file or database)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to determine the right way or the Angular way to provide data to directives for construction of the DOM. As my example, I'm trying to get JSON data from a file to construct a tree with jsTree. The problem is constructing the tree when the data has arrived and not beforehand.

I've solved the problem by `$watch`ing `treeData` in my controller. If I don't `$watch` it, the tree will be constructed with an empty array as input, and later, Angular will update the reference to populate the data. But I feel like this is the wrong way to do it since the data isn't going to change after the tree is initially constructed.

Here is my code

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('jsTreeApp', ['ngResource']);

var TestCtrl = function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.treeData = Data.getTreeData();
}

app.directive('jstree', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    scope.$watch('treeData.data', function() {
      $(element).jstree({
        "json_data" : scope.treeData,
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
      });
    })
  }
});

app.factory('Data', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/data/treeData.json', {}, {
    getTreeData: { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
  })
})
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jsTreeAngular</title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-app="jsTreeApp">
  <div jstree></div>
</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jstree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions for the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem with using the $watch, because you bind it, you need some way to see if the data is populated or not and to act upon it.

The problem that I see here is that it not obvious where the "treeData" is coming from, and that might confuse other developers.

What I would do instead is to define an isolated scope and to pass an attribute with the treeData, that way you can keep it loosely coupled and don't have to worry about changing the name of "treeData" in the controller.

you can define isolated scope like this:

```
app.directive('jstree', function() {

  return {
      scope: {
             treeData: "="
             }, 
      link: function(scope, element) {
         scope.$watch('treeData.data', function() {
           $(element).jstree({
             "json_data" : scope.treeData,
             "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
           });
         })
       }
    }
});
```